# Git failing to merge

Tags: git, merge

I created a branch called tmp, made a few commits and now when I'm trying to merge it fails. When I type `git branch -avvv` I see the following

```
master                f439a52 [origin/master] updated footer formatting
* tmp                 acc5818 added analytics and logos
remotes/origin/master f439a52 updated footer formatting
```

I then checked out master, tried to merge tmp, but I got a bunch of errors such as `CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in ....`

I tried to check tmp out again, but then it said `Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.` I have no idea what the conflict is, so I have no idea how to fix them. I want to keep all of the additions I've made in the tmp branch.

I typed `git reset --hard` and switched back to tmp. Then I deleted master, created a new master branch and tried to merge tmp, but the same thing happened again.

Comment: Um.. `git` doesn't always know how to merge with changes that touch the same lines of a file from both branches. You need to resolve them, use `git mergetool` and select which line to use from either tmp or master branch. After that, make sure code compiles and run tests etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a 
`git merge` it will actual modify the files that have conflicts and show you what the differences are. You'll have to manually edit the files that have conflicts and then commit those changes.

Example

```
<<<<<<<
Changes made on the branch that is being merged into. In most cases,
this is the branch that I have currently checked out (i.e. HEAD).
|||||||
The common ancestor version.
=======
Changes made on the branch that is being merged in. This is often a 
feature/topic branch.
>>>>>>>
```

Comment: I opened up a file and see something like this. I see a bunch of things labeled HEAD and tmp. Am I supposed to delete or add code? I don't really get what the issue is (or rather how git actually functions and tracks changes)

Comment: Head will be from the master branch that you are merging into. the bottom half will be for the branch that you are merging from. If you want just the code from tmp. Remove the Head section and the '>>>' generated by the merge. You'll have to decide which code is the correct code.

Comment: Note that the `|||...` and common-ancestor part is included only if you set `merge.conflictstyle` to `diff3`.